# Is this a bug or a complex coding solution with GridView formatting in edit mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, sql-server, gridview

I'm in the process of trying to determing if what I'm seeing is solvable via code or is a bug in GridView (Using Visual Studio 2012 Preimum/SQL Server 2012 - Patched to Current Standards with .NET 4.5 (4.0 used in code)).  Using Microsoft's AdventureWorks2012 for dB information.

I have a GridView that sits inside of a panel (the SQL Data is solid and works as I want it) which has a Frozen Header (with all the column names from  the database).  When the page loads, everything behaves as I want it.  However, when I go into edit mode the formatting that I set in non editing mode is gone and the panel that holds the GridView doesn't stretch out to fill/show the entire data and chops off a significant portion of the gridview.

I should also note the Freeze Pane still operates as normal. However, with the parts of the GridView that are cut off in edit mode this defeats the purpose of 1) the GridView and 2) the Freeze Pane.  I spent the better part of yesterday trying to figure out how I could apply the editing from initial page load to GridView editing mode.  I shouldn't have to do this but it's something that needs to be done.  I've been looking over the OnRowEditing Method as a possible answer as well as looking over the ASP options for GridView and Panel.  I've even looked over the CSS to see if there's a solution but I'm stumped.

What I'm hoping to accomplish is to have the formatting that I like when the page loads stay uniform when the GridView goes into edit mode.

Here's a sample of what I'm seeing (note how the GridView in the pane slides):

[image]

[image]

Yes, this is a sandbox database but what I'm seeing on my actual code is more information being cut off than this on the end.

I'm trying to learn this so some pointers on the theory behind this would be great as well.  Am I even on the right path by OnRowEditing method?

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="<path to>/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="<path to>/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
.header-frozen
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>


<br />

<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1"  Height="600px" Width="4000px" ScrollBars="Vertical" runat="server">


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="BusinessEntityID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessEntityID" HeaderText="Business Entity ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BusinessEntityID" InsertVisible="False" ShowHeader="False" >

        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NationalIDNumber" HeaderText="National ID #" SortExpression="NationalIDNumber" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LoginID" HeaderText="Login ID" SortExpression="LoginID" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationNode" HeaderText="Organization Node" SortExpression="OrganizationNode" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationLevel" HeaderText="Organization Level" SortExpression="OrganizationLevel" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTitle" HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="JobTitle" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MaritalStatus" HeaderText="Marital Status" SortExpression="MaritalStatus" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="Hire Date" SortExpression="HireDate" ShowHeader="False" />






        <asp:BoundField DataField="SalariedFlag" HeaderText="Salaried Flag" SortExpression="SalariedFlag" ShowHeader="False" />



        <asp:BoundField DataField="VacationHours" HeaderText="Vacation Hours" SortExpression="VacationHours" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" ShowHeader="False" />



        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentFlag" HeaderText="Current Flag" SortExpression="CurrentFlag" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rowguid" HeaderText="Row Guid" SortExpression="rowguid" ShowHeader="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="Modified Date" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" ShowHeader="False" />

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="header-frozen" Height="60px" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorks2012ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BusinessEntityID],[NationalIDNumber],[LoginID],[OrganizationNode],[OrganizationLevel],[JobTitle],[BirthDate],[MaritalStatus],[Gender],[HireDate],[SalariedFlag],[VacationHours],[SickLeaveHours],[CurrentFlag],[rowguid],[ModifiedDate] FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [HumanResources].[Employee] SET SELECT [NationalIDNumber] = @NationalIDNumber,[LoginID] = @LoginID,[OrganizationNode] = @OrganizationNode,[OrganizationLevel] = @OrganizationLevel,[JobTitle] = @JobTitle,[BirthDate] = @BirthDate,[MaritalStatus] = @MaritalStatus,[Gender] = @Gender,[HireDate] = @HireDate,[SalariedFlag] = @SalariedFlag,[VacationHours] = @VacationHours,[SickLeaveHours] = @SickLeaveHours,[CurrentFlag] = @CurrentFlag,[rowguid] = @rowguid,[ModifiedDate] = @ModifiedDate WHERE [BusinessEntityID] = @BusinessEntityID">
<UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="NationalIDNumber" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LoginID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganizationNode" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrganizationLevel" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BirthDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MaritalStatus" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="HireDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SalariedFlag" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="VacationHours" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SickLeaveHours" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CurrentFlag" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="rowguid" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BusinessEntityID" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you in a right way it is not the problem of the editing mode but is the problem with the css that you had used for the freezing of the header please try to change it..

Comment: try to set width of header and grid rows same it will work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by increasing the width of the panel to 9000 and everything seem to fit/work after that in edit mode.